# Is it possible to ask server side to execute a method without using RMI?

Tags: java, sockets, rmi

I couldn't try this out since I don't have a java web server. My idea is to sent a number to the server via sockets. The number sent will be dependent on user's response or requirement.

For example:
Consider a tic-tac-toe game. Let's imagine that the user lost the match and I want the user to enter `yes` to replay or `no` to exit.

If the user enters `yes` , the program will write a number (eg. 1) to the `outputstream` of the socket. Now, the server receives the number using `inputstream` and stores it in an integer variable. If it finds that the number entered is `1` , the game begins again. There will be methods which handle these numbers received.

Is it possible to communicate with the server and invoke a remote method in this manner?

If yes, why was RMI designed when it can be done by coding (pretty easily)?

Comment: What do you mean, you "don't have" a Web server? Spring Boot and similar tools make launching one trivial.

Comment: @chrylis I couldn't configure Tomcat.

Comment: Spring Boot does it all for you!

Comment: Is Spring Boot a software like Xampp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to communicate with the server

Yes.

> and invoke a remote method

No. The server is invoking the method locally. You're just sending it a number telling it what to do. No remote method invocation here.

> why was RMI designed when it can be done by coding (pretty easily)?

RMI provides a syntax for calling a remote method directly, without having to worry about:

- connections
- method numbers
- wire specifications for request and response
- marshalling the arguments
- unmarshalling the response
- turning some responses into exceptions
- ensuring that all responses obey exception semantics
- dynamic class loading
- ...

You can certainly reimplement all that yourself, and of course RMI is implemented in Java as well, but don't underestimate the scope, or the difficulty.

Comment: My idea was to send a number to the servef via socket. The server receives this and a method will test this number and invoke a method according. Wouldn't this work?

Comment: Of course it would work. Nobody has said otherwise. That's what RMI does, under the hood, among many other things.

Comment: Okay. One last doubt. In servers, usually a loop keeps running waiting for a connection request from a user. Since, this loop is running forever, doesn't it lead to any stackoverflow exception on the server (since it is an infinite loop) ?

Comment: @MathewsMathai I don't understand why you're even asking. *Recursion* leads to stack overflows. Infinite loops don't.